# Python : looping through each row of html table based on headers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python(3.4) and have parsed an html table into headings[ ] , rows[ ] and cells [ ]
I wish to store each of these into a table (MySQL) eventually with the field names being the items in the headings[ ]

There are 4 headings("data0","data1","data2","data3")
There are 6 rows

The code to get there is very rudimentary using BeautifulSoup:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
table = soup.find("table")
cells = []
rows = table.findAll('tr')
headings = [th.get_text().strip() for th in table.findAll("th")]
for row in rows:
    for cell in row.findAll('td')
    cells .append(cell.get_text().strip())
```

I'm used to doing CASE statements, or, heaven forbid, a number of IF statements. I would normally place them under the 
for cell in row.findAll('td')  . But I would be working with a counter and be doing something like:

```
for row = 0 to len(rows)
    for cell = 0 to len(headings)
         select case cell
    case = 0 
      (save cell contents to field called headings[0]
    case = 1
      (save cell contents to field called headings[1]       
...
```

I'm not too worried about the saving part (yet) but I cant wrap my head around not being able to use counters.
I realize this is way beginner, but I should would appreciate any insight (and so would my brain)

Comment: Your code and comments are not very clear as to what you are attempting to accomplish. especially when you say `not being able to use counters` - could you please expand on your question?

Comment: It looks like this question is not really about HTML parsing, more about Python `for` loops, is that correct? Also, you _can_ use counters in loops (the pythonic way to do so is using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#enumerate)), but maybe all you really need is [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#zip)?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. Yes, the problem has to do with loops but perhaps the answer is the way that I'm doing it initially - that's why the HTML.   I have a list that has all the cell contents for each row. I also have a list that has the headers.  I want to make sure that if the page adds a header or subtracts a header, I just want the first 4 cells for each row. If they delete one header (column=3) I would need to only take 3 cells. My cell list currently has 64 elements. How do I differentiate - or is my initial scraping and getting all cells in a list the wrong approach?